# Comments form same for logged and the guest

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I need to have same comments form for logged users and guests. Now, when user is logged in in form there aren't some additional fields e.g. author, email etc.

I was trying to get this with code, but when I put content of my form there I'm getting two comment forms, one below other (wihtout fields I want e.g author,email).

```
 <?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
comment form for logged users
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Content of my comments.php

```
<?php $comment_args = array(
'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
'author' => ' <div class="col-md-3">' . ( $req ? '' : '' ) .
'<input id="author" name="author" placeholder="Imię" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' />',   
'email'  => '' . ( $req ? '' : '' ) .
'<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' />',
'url'    => '' ) ),
'comment_field' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-9"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Treść..." rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></div>',
'comment_notes_after' => '',
'class_submit'         => 'submit',
'label_submit' => 'DODAJ KOMENTARZ',
'submit_field' => '<p class="form-submit">%1$s %2$s</p></div>'
);

comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

Comment: Here you need to use `else`. `if (logged) show_form_1 else show_form_2`

Comment: Unfortunately even with use of else fields like author, email doesn't display